When I will upload the CSV data in blob storage how can my azure ML notebook will get retrained
I am working on a project where I will upload the data in blob storage in azure then my azure machine learning notebook will get restrained and give the updated.pkl file.
I need the solution for the above how can I do that and will do the deployment.

To Re-train your model each time a file is updated or a new file arrive you can use a change based trigger in ML Azure.
but you must specify the right directory because changes within subdirectories of that directory will not trigger a job.
